# Insert TOC in Word Document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an Excel worksheet which has list of links to Html files. I loop through these html files and insert each file into a word document while creating heading 1 references which i later use to create a TOC.  Right now everything works from excel VBA except the TOC part, i am able to create the TOC manually using the word> references > insert TOC.  However the VBA code for TablesofContents.Add give an error

> "Run-time error 13 - Type mismacth"

If i remove the TOC VBA code rest of the macro runs as i expect. Not quite sure what is wrong with the code.

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim rngA As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 'Need this to interact 
  with the windows filesystem
Set wd = CreateObject("word.application") ' need this to open any word documents


DQ = Chr(34) ' double quote will used later for string processing

Set F = fso.GetFolder(InputBox("Enter location where Collated Document is to 
 be created"))
 orent = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter Orientation 1 for Landscape, 0 
 for Portrait ")
Typ = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter type")


If orent = 1 Then
    orentt = "Landscape"
ElseIf orent = 0 Then
   orentt = "Portrait"
 End If

 Set rngA = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

 wd.Documents.Add
  wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs F & "\" & "TLF_collated.docx"
  wd.Documents.Open F & "\" & "TLF_collated.docx"

With wd.ActiveDocument
    .PageSetup.Orientation = orent
    .Paragraphs.LineUnitAfter = 0
    .Paragraphs.LineUnitBefore = 0
    '.Selection.wholestory
    '.Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"



  End With






 For Each cell In rngA

 If cell.Value = Typ Then


   wd.Selection.Style = ("Heading 1")
    wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=Typ & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & " : " 
    & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    wd.Selection.TypeParagraph
    wd.Selection.InsertFile CStr(Replace(Replace(cell.Offset(0, 4).Formula, 
    "=HYPERLINK(" & DQ, ""), DQ & "," & DQ & cell.Offset(0, 4).Value & DQ & 
       ")", ""))
    wd.Selection.EndKey
    wd.Selection.InsertBreak 3
    wd.Selection.InsertBreak 2



 End If
 Next cell

Set myrange = wd.Selection
    myrange.WholeStory
    myrange.Font.Name = "Arial"
    myrange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    myrange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0

     wd.Selection.HomeKey
     wd.Selection.MoveUp

       wd.TablesOfContents.Add myrange, _
                                UseFields:=True, _
                                UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
                                UpperHeadingLevel:=1


wd.ActiveDocument.Save
wd.ActiveDocument.Close


 End Sub
```

Comment: `Set myrange = wd.Selection`. Are you sure myrange is a valid object to pass to `wd.TablesOfContents.Add`? check all the arguments in that method against what you are passing. `Type Mismatch` error implies you are passing an incorrect object type into an argument.

Comment: my VBA knowledge is very limited, I assume when i set myrange=wd.Selection and use it in TOC.add it  will look at the whole document to build the TOC.  if remove myrange , the error changes to "Argument not optional".

Comment: you are getting what i am saying. now just make sure that wd.Selection qualifies as valid range to pass in that instance...  checking the [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/tablesofcontents-add-method-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clearly shows this where the error is. the range argument shows where you actually want to *place* the TOC, not what you want to consider in the TOC range.

Comment: @Scott. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. i set a Set myRange = wd.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0) and it placed TOC at the top of the document. I should have asked the question sooner i spent some hours trying to figure it out.  Thanks Again.

Comment: We've all spent hours (or days even) trying to figure it out only to find someone else give us the answer in seconds :) And I'm sure we'll do it some more too :) Glad you got it.